# How to trace when a twilio call was rejected by callee and redirected to voicemail

Tags: javascript, twilio

I'm developing app for phone calls by using Twilio Voice SDK in JavaScript. But I have met issue. If a call rejected and redirected to voicemail I want to know it. So when calle hit the red button on his phone I want to know it. But in my case I just redirected to voicemail and call continues. Is there any event or something?

A standard event like reject or cancel works only for incoming calls but not for outgoing, pls help me

Answer (score 0):

[Answering Machine Detection (AMD)](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/answering-machine-detection) enables you to determine the receiving side of an outgoing call and tailor your call flow accordingly. With AMD you can determine if a human, answering machine or fax machine has picked up an outbound voice API call. Once AMD has executed and made its decision, the caller is connected to the callee.

```js
// Download the helper library from https://www.twilio.com/docs/node/install
// Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
// and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.calls
  .create({
     machineDetection: 'Enable',
     url: 'https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/EH8ccdbd7f0b8fe34357da8ce87ebe5a16',
     to: '+1562300000',
     from: '+18180000000'
   })
  .then(call => console.log(call.sid));
```

Also make sure to check out the [FAQ & Best Practices Guide](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/answering-machine-detection-faq-best-practices).